# Make \droptotalpoints look like \droppoints (exam documentclass)

Tags: calculations, exam

To save typing, I have `\newcommand{\q}{\question[1]}` defined in my `exam` documentclass. Then, after the question, I use `\droppoints` to get `[1 pt]` printed in the right margin.

But sometimes, my questions have parts, each of which is to be worth 1 point each, like this

```
\q ...
\begin{parts}
    \part[1] ...
    \part[1] ...
    \part[1] ...
    \part[1] ...
\end{parts}
```

If I try to use `\droppoints` here, it will give me a `[1 pt]`, because the last part was worth one point.

If I try to use `\droptotalpoints` here, it gives me a whole big text that I can't get rid of.

I can, of course, write the question as `\question[4]` and then after the last part say `\droppoints`. This works great unless I decide to add or comment out a part.

*Is it possible for me to get the same point display at the end of a question while automatically summing up the parts?* Also, can this be done relatively simply so that I can understand the answer (and modify in the nearly certain case that I change my mind about what I want).

**EDIT** Per the comment, here is a (sort of) MWE. But it only shows the problem, not the way I'd like it to look.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust that with `\totalformat` command.

```
\totalformat{\fbox{\bfseries Total: \totalpoints\ pts}}
```

Do your customizations here.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\totalformat{\fbox{\bfseries Total: \totalpoints\ pts}}
\pointpoints{pt}{pts}
\bracketedpoints

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question How are you?
\droptotalpoints             %% put this here
\begin{parts}
    \part[1] ...
    \droppoints
    \part[2] ...
    \droppoints
    \part[1] ...
    \droppoints
    \part[1] ...
    \droppoints
\end{parts}
%\droptotalpoints            %% put this just after the question
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]